# What could the following gcc compilation error mean and why does it have a part that looks like the encoding is corrupted?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, mingw

When trying to `make` a C program, I get the following error, what could it mean and why does the the forth line contain question marks?

```
C:\xxxxx\yyyyy\zzzz>make
cc gcc -I.   -c -o facetrain.o facetrain.c
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc gcc -I. -c -o facetrain.o facetrain.c, ...) failed.
make (e=2): ?e? e??a? d??at? ? e??es? t?? ?a????s╡???? a??e??? ap? t? s?st?╡a.
make: *** [<builtin>: facetrain.o] Error 2
```

The Makefile
As you may notice, if you take a look at the source code (I provide the link below), I have changed the compiler in the cflag to match the mingw compiler.

```
CFLAGS=gcc -I.
LFLAGS=

facetrain: facetrain.o imagenet.o backprop_initr.o pgmimage.o
    $(CC) ${LFLAGS} facetrain.o imagenet.o backprop_initr.o pgmimage.o \
          -o facetrain -lm

hidtopgm: hidtopgm.o pgmimage.o backprop_initr.o
    $(CC) ${LFLAGS} hidtopgm.o pgmimage.o backprop_initr.o \
          -o hidtopgm -lm

outtopgm: outtopgm.o pgmimage.o backprop_initr.o
    $(CC) ${LFLAGS} outtopgm.o pgmimage.o backprop_initr.o \
          -o outtopgm -lm

facetrain_init0: facetrain.o imagenet.o backprop_init0.o pgmimage.o
    $(CC) ${LFLAGS} facetrain.o imagenet.o backprop_init0.o pgmimage.o \
          -o facetrain_init0 -lm

backprop_initr.o: backprop.c backprop.h
    $(CC) ${CFLAGS} -c backprop.c
    mv backprop.o backprop_initr.o

backprop_init0.o: backprop.c backprop.h
    $(CC) ${CFLAGS} -c -DINITZERO backprop.c
    mv backprop.o backprop_init0.o
```

The rest of the source code:
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/project/theo-8/faceimages/code/

The environment:
Windows 10 uning MinGW, gcc -v:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --target=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --with-arch=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain your encoding issues but your error is easy to explain:

```
CFLAGS=gcc -I.
```

You've added "gcc" to the flags, then you invoke the compiler like this:

```
$(CC) ${CFLAGS} ...
```

so as you can see from the command make prints you get:

```
cc gcc -I.  ...
```

as the compile line.

You should set the compiler separately:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -I.
```

Comment: oh god.. I totally missed that, I can't believe I wasted so my time on this.. tnx!!! (now I got a bunch of `implicit declaration of function` warnings)